# Time since last update of a file in human readable format

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to get the time since the last update of a file in a human readable format. On the Internet I found:

```
now=$(date +%s) # to get timestamp of now
last=$(stat -c %Y /var/cache/apt/) # to get the timestamp of the last update
```

But now I want to divide `now` with `last` and print it in a human readable format in Debian shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function:

```
time_since() {
  file=$1
  now=$(date +%s)
  file_time=$(stat -c %Y "$file")
  seconds=$((now - file_time))
  hh=$((  $seconds / 3600 ))
  mm=$(( ($seconds - $hh * 3600) / 60 ))
  ss=$((  $seconds - $hh * 3600 - $mm * 60 ))
  printf '%d:%02d:%02d\n' $hh $mm $ss
}

time_since /var/cache/apt
# output => 332:17:07
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `bash` & `printf`:

```
time_since() {
        eval "$(stat -s "$1")"  # st_mtime=1490029104
        TZ=UTC printf "%(%T)T\n" $(( $(printf "%(%s)T") - st_mtime ))
}
time_since file.txt
#out -> 02:07:02
```

Some *duration value* (time difference in seconds) is the same as the epoch time. (e.g. the difference in seconds from the epoch (UTC))